# How to rotate only the canvas behind the text

Tags: java, android, animation, android-canvas, rotateanimation

I have this function that animate the image canvas from resource drawable with text on the front.

I want to rotate the a green "star" only so the text stay intact

[image]

The idea is to rotate only the image canvas but no the text.
How do I do that?

**This code is for Android Java**

```
 private Bitmap writeTextOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text, ImageView imv_promo,boolean isAnim) {

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "RobotoCondensed-Italic.ttf");

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(mContext, 17));


    Rect textRect = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);

    //If the text is bigger than the canvas , reduce the font size
    if (textRect.width() >= (canvas.getWidth() - 4))     //the padding on either sides is considered as 4, so as to appropriately fit in the text
        paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(mContext, 7));        //Scaling needs to be used for different dpi's

    //Calculate the positions
    int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - 6;     //-2 is for regulating the x position offset

    int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2));

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate((float) 25, xPos, yPos);
    canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);
    canvas.restore();

    Animation animation;
    if(isAnim) {
        animation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        animation.setDuration(20000L);
        imv_promo.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    return bm;
}
```

Comment: what actually do you want to rotate? a green "star" only having 15% stay intact?

Comment: Yes,  only rotate the green star

Comment: @pskind can you do that?